# Using different C++ headers to replace bit headers

Tags: c++, xcode, header

I'm trying to compile an OpenCV open source code project but it is using these headers...

```
#include <bits/stl_list.h>
#include <bits/stl_vector.h>
```

I'm using Xcode and it can't regconize these headers. Is it possible to replace this with headers like...

```
#include <list.h>
#include <vector.h>
```

When I do, it breaks parts of the code which references the bit headers. It seems like they're still just referencing things like `List<int>` which would make me think that I could replace the headers to get the code to work.

Is it possible to install bit headers into my C++ library to get the project to compile?

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <bits/stl_list.h>
#include <bits/stl_vector.h>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "My_Q.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
//=========controller parameters=================
const int MAX_CORNERS = 100;
const int frame_queue_size = 50 ;
const float threshold_percent = 0.1;

const bool draw_floor_line = true;

const bool webcam_mode = false;
const string movie_address = "sample_videos/1p1.mp4";//1p1,people,2p1
//======camera calibration parameters============
const float fku = 1000;
const float v0 = 100;
const float h = 1;
//=======global variables========================
int number_of_people;

CvPoint2D32f* features;
int features_number=0;

int* setNumbers;
int* height_from_floor;

void MyLine( Mat img, Point start, Point end )
{
    int thickness = 1;
    int lineType = 8;
    line( img,
         start,
         end,
         Scalar( 0,255, 255 ),
         thickness,
         lineType );
}
CvPoint2D32f* find_features(Mat image,vector <Rect> Rect_list,
                            int & features_number)
{
    //cout<<"4.2.1"<<endl;
    list<CvPoint2D32f> features;
    list<int> set_number;
    list<int> dist2B;

    int RectNumber = Rect_list.size();
    int i, j;
    int All_features_number=0;
    //cout<<"4.2.2"<<endl;
    for (i=0; i<RectNumber; i++)
    {
        Rect r = Rect_list[i];
        ////=================cropping=================================
        //cout<<"4.2.3"<<endl;
        cout<<r.x<<','<<r.y<<endl;
        //Mat cropped_rectangle(image, r);
        Mat cropped_rectangle ;
        image(r).copyTo(cropped_rectangle);//crop r to cropped_rectangle
        //cout<<"4.2.4"<<endl;
        ////=================extracting good features=================
        IplImage* imgA = new IplImage(cropped_rectangle);//convert matrix
        //cropped_rectangle to IplImage
        CvSize img_sz = cvGetSize(imgA);
        IplImage* eig_image = cvCreateImage( img_sz, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1 );
        //scratch image
        IplImage* tmp_image =cvCreateImage(img_sz,IPL_DEPTH_32F,1);
        //scratch image
        int corner_count = MAX_CORNERS;
        //The corner_count indicates the maximum number of points
        // for which there
        //is space to return. After the routine exits, corner_count
        //is overwritten by the number
        //of points that were actually found
        //cout<<"4.2.5"<<endl;
        CvPoint2D32f* cornersA = new CvPoint2D32f[ MAX_CORNERS ];
        // good feature points
        //cout<<"4.2.6"<<endl;
        cvGoodFeaturesToTrack(//fine good features of rectangle
                              imgA,
                              eig_image,
                              tmp_image,
                              cornersA,
                              &corner_count,
                              0.01,
                              5.0,
                              0,
                              3,
                              0,
                              0.04
                              );
        //========================

        //========================
        //cout<<"4.2.7"<<endl;
        ////===mapping good features to the original picture and add them to the list
        //of features and set their set(the rectangle they are belonging)===
        for(int k = 0;k<corner_count;k++)
        {
            int distance = r.height - cornersA[k].y;
            dist2B.push_back(distance);

            cornersA[k].x= r.x+ cornersA[k].x;//mapping
            cornersA[k].y= r.y+ cornersA[k].y;//mapping
            features.push_back(cornersA[k]);//adding

            set_number.push_back(i);

        }
        //cout<<"4.2.8"<<endl;
        All_features_number+=corner_count;

    }
    CvPoint2D32f* features_array = new CvPoint2D32f[All_features_number];
    setNumbers = new int[All_features_number];
    height_from_floor = new int [All_features_number];
    int iter = 0;
    //cout<<"4.2.9"<<endl;
    while (features.size() > 0)
    //copy the features list to the final features array
    {
        CvPoint2D32f F_point = features.front();
        features_array[iter].x = F_point.x;
        features_array[iter].y = F_point.y;
        features.pop_front();

        int SN = set_number.front();
        setNumbers[iter] = SN;
        set_number.pop_front();

        int d = dist2B.front();
        height_from_floor[iter] = d;
        dist2B.pop_front();
        iter++;
    }
    //cout<<"4.2.10"<<endl;
    features_number=All_features_number;
    return features_array;
}
int people_floor(int p, bool & status)
{
    int sum=0;
    int m=0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i< features_number;i++)
    if (setNumbers[i]== p)
    {
        sum+=(features[i].y+height_from_floor[i]);
        m++;
    }
    if(m==0)
    {
        status = false;
        return 0;
    }
    status = true;
    return(sum/m);
}
int scaled_people_floor(int p,bool &status)
{
    int y = people_floor(p,status);
    if(!status)
    return -1;
    float sum=0;
    float m = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<features_number;i++)
    {
        if(setNumbers[i]==setNumbers[p])
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<features_number;j++)
            {
                if(setNumbers[j]==setNumbers[p])
                {
                    if(height_from_floor[i]-height_from_floor[j]<2)
                    continue;
                    float t = (features[i].y-features[j].y)/(height_from_floor[i]-height_from_floor[j]);
                    if(t<0)
                    t=-t;
                    sum+= t;
                    m++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(m==0)
    {
        return(y);
    }
    float alpha = sum/m;
    return(alpha*y);
}
float compute_distance(int v)
{
    return((fku*h)/(v-v0));
}
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int screen_width;
    int screen_height;
    VideoCapture cap;
    if(!webcam_mode)
    {
        VideoCapture cap1(movie_address);
        screen_width = cap1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
        screen_height =cap1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
        cap = cap1;
    }
    else
    {
        VideoCapture cap2(0);
        screen_width = 640;
        screen_height =480;
        cap2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, screen_width);//1024,320,640,160
        cap2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, screen_height);//768,240,480,120
        cap = cap2;
    }


    if (!cap.isOpened())
    return -1;
    namedWindow("video capture", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    Mat current_frame;
    Mat next_frame;
    Mat current_frame_copy;
    HOGDescriptor hog;
    hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());
    int Threshold=0;
    while(1)//main loop:
    {

        vector<Rect> found, found_filtered;
        CvPoint2D32f* tracked_features;
        ////****************************************************************************
        ////**********************detection loop: **********************************
        while(1)//detection loop
        {
            cout<<"start detection loop\n";
            ////--------delete info of previous iteration---------
            found_filtered.clear();
            //--------------get next frame------------------------
            cap >> current_frame;
            if(! current_frame.data )// Check for invalid input
            {
                cout<<"no frame"<<endl;
                return 0;
            }
            current_frame.copyTo(current_frame_copy);
            //convert it to the gray
            cvtColor(current_frame, current_frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
            //cout<<"2"<<endl;
            //---------------detection with HOG algorithm---------
            hog.detectMultiScale(current_frame,
                                 found,
                                 0,
                                 Size(8,8),
                                 Size(32,32),
                                 1.05,
                                 2);
            cout<<"HOG detection Done"<<endl;
            //filter redundant rectangles
            for (int i=0; i<found.size(); i++)
            {
                Rect r = found[i];
                int j;
                for (j=0; j<found.size(); j++)
                if (j!=i && (r & found[j])==r)
                break;
                if (j==found.size())
                found_filtered.push_back(r);
            }
            number_of_people = found_filtered.size();
            //cout<<"4"<<endl;
            //----------extracting good features for tracking------
            if(number_of_people>0)//if at least one person found:
            {
                // cout<<"4.1"<<endl;
                for(int i=0;i<found_filtered.size();i++)
                //bound rectangles to the screen
                {
                    if(found_filtered[i].x<0)
                    found_filtered[i].x =0;
                    if(found_filtered[i].y<0)
                    found_filtered[i].y =0;
                    if(found_filtered[i].x+found_filtered[i].width>screen_width)
                    found_filtered[i].width =screen_width-found_filtered[i].x;
                    if(found_filtered[i].y+found_filtered[i].height>screen_height)
                    found_filtered[i].height =screen_height-found_filtered[i].y;
                }
                try// find the list of features of the people
                {
                    // cout<<"4.2"<<endl;
                    features = find_features(current_frame,
                                             found_filtered,
                                             features_number);
                    // cout<<"4.3"<<endl;
                }
                catch(Exception exp)
                {
                    cout<<"exception find features error"<<endl;
                    continue;
                }

                break;
            }
            //cout<<"4.4.1"<<endl;

            //------------showing detection
            imshow("video capture", current_frame_copy);
            waitKey(10);
            cout<<"end detection loop"<<endl;
        }
        ////===========setting the breaking threshold for the tracking=========
        //cout<<"4.5"<<endl;
        Threshold = features_number*threshold_percent;
        //cout<<"4.6, feature_number="<<features_number
        //  <<",Threshold="<<Threshold<<endl;
        My_Q Queue(frame_queue_size,1);
        ////****************************************************************************
        ////***********************//tracking loop: ********************************
        while(1)//tracking loop
        {
            cout<<"tracking loop start"<<endl;

            ////==================check for breaking conditions===============
            Queue.AddNew(features_number);
            if(Queue.BreakCondition())
            {
                cout<<"features # are not changing for a while!"<<endl;
                break;
            }
            if(features_number< Threshold)
            //check for enough number of features to track
            {
                cout<<"features less than threshold"<<endl;
                break;
                //go to the detection loop when number of
                //tracked features is less than an arbitrary threshold
            }
            ////======================reading the next frame================
            current_frame_copy.setTo(Scalar(0,0,0));
            //cout<<"t00"<<endl;

            cap >> next_frame;//get the next frame
            //cout<<"t01"<<endl;
            if(! next_frame.data )// Check for invalid input
            {
                cout<<"Frame not captured"<<endl;
                return 0;
                //continue;
            }
            next_frame.copyTo(current_frame_copy);
            cvtColor(next_frame, next_frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
            //convert it to gray scale
            //cout<<"t02";
            ////=====================tracking using LK ==============================
            try
            {
                ////-----------LK parameters-------------
                char status[features_number];
                //shows the status of points. 0 means
                // feature lost; 1 means found
                float feature_errors[features_number];
                //list of lost features
                tracked_features= new CvPoint2D32f[ features_number ];
                IplImage* imgA = new IplImage(current_frame);
                //convert initial matrix image to IplImage
                IplImage* imgB = new IplImage(next_frame);
                //convert final matrix image to IplImage
                CvSize pyr_sz = cvSize( imgA->width+8, imgB->height/3 );
                IplImage* pyrA = cvCreateImage( pyr_sz, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1 );
                IplImage* pyrB = cvCreateImage( pyr_sz, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1 );
                int win_size = 10;
                cout<<"before LK"<<endl;
                //--------------------------------------
                cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK(
                                       imgA,//initial image
                                       imgB,
                                       //final image,both should be single-channel, 8-bit images.
                                       pyrA,
                                       //buffer allocated to store the pyramid images
                                       pyrB,
                                       features,
                                       ////the array contains the points
                                       //for which the motion is to be found
                                       tracked_features,////similar array into
                                       //which the computed new locations of the points
                                       ////from features are to be placed
                                       features_number,////feature_number is the number
                                       //of points in the features list
                                       cvSize( win_size,win_size ),
                                       5,
                                       status,
                                       feature_errors,
                                       cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 20, .3 ),
                                       0
                                       );
                cout<<"LK done"<<endl;
                ////============updating the info after tracking===================
                //updating feature points
                //removing info (set_number/distance to bottom) of lost features
                int new_feature_number = 0;
                int * temp_set_number = new int[features_number];
                int * temp_distance = new int[features_number];
                int j = 0;
                for(int i = 0 ;i<features_number;i++)
                {
                    if(status[i] == 1)
                    {
                        new_feature_number++;
                        //counting number of features tracked successfully

                        temp_set_number[j]=setNumbers[i];
                        temp_distance[j]= height_from_floor[i];
                        j++;
                    }
                }
                setNumbers = temp_set_number;
                height_from_floor = temp_distance;

                features_number = new_feature_number;
                cout<<"features_number="<<features_number<<endl;
                delete[] features;
                features = new CvPoint2D32f[ features_number ] ;
                for(int i = 0;i<features_number;i++)//update features
                {
                    features[i]=tracked_features[i];
                }
                delete[] tracked_features;
                next_frame.copyTo(current_frame);
                cout<<"info updated after LK"<<endl;
            }
            catch(Exception exp)
            {
                cout<<"LK-exception"<<endl;
                break;
            }
            ////****************************************************************************
            ////****************************computing distance******************************
            for(int p=0;p<number_of_people;p++)
            {
                bool status;
                int v = scaled_people_floor(p,status);
                //int v = people_floor(p);
                if(status)
                {
                    float d = compute_distance(v);
                    if(draw_floor_line)
                    MyLine(current_frame_copy,Point(0,v),Point(screen_width,v));

                    string dist_text = static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << d) )->str();
                    dist_text = dist_text.substr(0,5);
                    putText(current_frame_copy, "distance: "+dist_text+"m", Point(screen_width-150,screen_height-p*50-20),
                            CV_FONT_NORMAL, 0.5,CV_RGB((125-p*100)%255,(p*100)%255,(255-p*100)%255),1,1);
                }

            }
            cout<<"computing distance"<<endl;

            ////================showing points ======================

            for(int i=0;i<features_number;i++)
            {
                int p =  setNumbers[i];
                circle(current_frame_copy,
                       features[i],
                       1,
                       CV_RGB((125-p*100)%255,(p*100)%255,(255-p*100)%255),
                       3);
            }
            imshow("video capture", current_frame_copy);
            waitKey(10);
            cout<<"tracking loop end"<<endl;
        }
        cout<<"main loop end"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Those headers are not standard headers. I think they're part of gcc's library implementation, and some people think it's cool to use them instead of standard stuff. You're better off using the standard headers and figuring out what, if anything, needs to be fixed.

Comment: Side note - standard name for those headers are `<vector>` and `<list>`. (No .h suffix)

Comment: If the library author wrote `#include <bits/stl_list.h>`, then you can probably expect low code quality all around. Considering using a different library.

Comment: `using namespace std;` is another warning sign that the library writer wants you to fail.

Comment: @user4581301, how about this line? `string dist_text = static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << d) )->str();` this is beyond salvation

Comment: I can grasp the what and why of that line, but the readability is weak compared to a `string tostr(int)` function and the compiler would dissolve all of the overhead.